# tag cloud, layout: horizontal, and Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: layout, label, titanium, appcelerator, ellipsis

**Please note:** This question relates to the Appcelerator Titanium platform, not the stock iOS SDK.

I'm making a tag cloud with a `layout: horizontal` view. I'm most of the way there, but I can't get the final `Titanium.UI.Label` on a line to wrap if it doesn't fit. Instead, it gets ellipsized (in a useless manner).

[image]

Is there a way I can prevent this on iOS? Seems to work fine on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to set the label width to auto, Titanium will calculate the label width in runtime.
It make sense to get a ellipsized label in horizontal view.

You may need to determine the dynamic label width in your tag cloud case. But just leave it to titanium, you just need to change the dynamic width to static width with this tricky code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: data[i], width: 'auto', height: 20,left: 5, top: 5});

            label.width = label.width + 5; //this determine width in runtime assign back to static width
            view.add(label);
        }
```

Comment: You are my freaking HERO. Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully this helps some other poor soul, as i've wasted almost an entire day on this. label.width is now read only so it requires a different trick to force rendering. This works for me:
`label.setWidth(label.toImage().width)`
and likely this as well, but I haven't tested just yet:
`label.width = label.toImage().width`


this also provides some nice potential solutions:
https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120619/how-to-get-label-size

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone's answer to this is `minimumFontSize` but that makes no sense in a tag cloud... Have you considered adding this to a horizontal scrollview and setting the `contentWidth` to `auto`?

Also does each of your label have it's `width` set to `'auto'`? I imagine setting that would cause the word to overflow the `layout` and be pushed down to the next line.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding it to a horizontal scrollview. I don't want it to all be on one, scrollable line. Each one is set to 'auto' (you can see they're not set widths, each label is different width in the screenshot).

Comment: minimumFontSize works a treat in a non-tag cloud example